# Kotlin, Recyclerview reusing items but updating item colour

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that is being used to form a calendar. I have a custom flow that is used to populate 42 `DayOfMonth` tiles, and an observer to submit it to the adapter.

My aim was to have tiles from the next and previous month shown in grey (these are sometimes shown in the first and last row, depending on where the first day of the month lies).

[image]

When the user clicks on a tile in the next/previous month the flow updates and the calendar updates to center on that month. The tiles should adjust to their new positions and be coloured accordingly. However, if a tile is grey when it is created it does not change its colour. I assume the if statement defining its colour is not rechecked.

[image]

I assume this is because the recyclerview is reusing the tiles and not recreating them. This makes sense and the DiffUtil callback isnt actioned because the items are the same items (just in a different adapter position).

AdapterActivitiesCalendar

```
class AdapterActivitiesCalendar(
    private val listener: OnItemClickListener,
    private val viewLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    private val dateItemSelected: LiveData<Long>
) : ListAdapter<DayOfMonthItem, AdapterActivitiesCalendar.DateItemViewHolder>(DiffCallItem()) {
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DateItemViewHolder {
        return DateItemViewHolder(RvItemCalendarDayOfMonthTileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DateItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }

    inner class DateItemViewHolder(private var binding: RvItemCalendarDayOfMonthTileBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.apply {
                llItemHeader.setOnClickListener {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val dayOfMonthItem = getItem(position)
                        listener.onClickDayOfMonthTile(dayOfMonthItem)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Bind database information to item view
        fun bind(item: DayOfMonthItem) {
            binding.apply {

                tvDate.text = item.dayOfMonth.toString()

                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                if (((adapterPosition < 14) && (item.dayOfMonth > 14)) || ((adapterPosition > 28) && (item.dayOfMonth < 14))) {
                    tvDate.setTextColor(R.color.colourGrey)
                    ivIndicatorEvent.imageAlpha = 25
                    ivIndicatorActivity.imageAlpha = 25
                } else{                  
                    //tvDate.setTextColor(R.color.colourBlack)
                    //ivIndicatorEvent.imageAlpha = 100
                    //ivIndicatorActivity.imageAlpha = 100
                }

                dateItemSelected.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                    val position = adapterPosition
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        val dayOfMonthItem = getItem(position)
                        //converts to day, rather than long to remove HH:mm:ss
                        if (convertLongToDate(dayOfMonthItem.timestamp) == convertLongToDate(dateItemSelected.value!!)) {
                            llItemHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vec_border)
                        } else {
                            llItemHeader.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundColour)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Fragment Interface
    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onClickDayOfMonthTile(dayOfMonthItem: DayOfMonthItem)
        fun onDragDayOfMonthTile(dayOfMonthItem: DayOfMonthItem)
        fun onHoldDayOfMonthTile(dayOfMonthItem: DayOfMonthItem)
    }

    // update list when changes are made to the repository flow
    class DiffCallItem : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DayOfMonthItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DayOfMonthItem, newItem: DayOfMonthItem) =
            oldItem.timestamp == newItem.timestamp

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DayOfMonthItem, newItem: DayOfMonthItem) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
```

I've been working on the recyclerview and with DiffUtil to try to get it to recheck the position when updated but have had no luck.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Edit:**

ViewModel List

```
  val dayOfMonthList = dayOfMonthFlow.asLiveData()
```

Fragment Observer

```
viewModel.dayOfMonthList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
     calendarAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From doing a little more testing. The `dayOfMonth` tiles that are in both the existing list and new list (1-7 in the images) are unchanged when submit() is called in the observer (therefore each item's if statement isn’t run to update the text colour).

From what I've read and tried an imperfect solution is to clear the existing list from the RecyclerView adapter before submitting the new list. This means the lists aren’t compared and all items will be created when the new list is submitted. I recognise this isn’t ideal and might produce issues if the list was very large, however with 42 items it seems to work well enough.

The required change to the code is simply:

Observer

```
viewModel.dayOfMonthList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
     calendarAdapter.submitList(null) //added this line
     calendarAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your `areContentsTheSame` needs to be improved. It will return true even when being moved to the next month, which means it won't make any changes to it. I'm not sure how to do it right and efficient but simply changing it to

```
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DayOfMonthItem, newItem: DayOfMonthItem) = false
```

should work.

Though you probably also need to comment this back in

```
                //tvDate.setTextColor(R.color.colourBlack)
                //ivIndicatorEvent.imageAlpha = 100
                //ivIndicatorActivity.imageAlpha = 100
```

Comment: Thanks Ivo, 
Yes I've been trying to figure out how to compare the adapter position or layout position within the DiffUtil as this is the aspect of each tile which has changed. 

And uncommenting this code turns all tile text grey. I havent figured why but there is a bug in the logic somewhere. I'll deal with this, thanks for the thought

Comment: tvdate.setTextColor(R.color.colourBlack) does not work correctly. Updated to: tvDate.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(tvDate.context,R.color.colourBlack)). This however doesnt resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to your images, when you change the month (Next or Previous).
You need to update whole list of the adapter and need to call notifyDatasetChanged(). i am sure you are calling that.

But i you look at the code in bind.
[image]

```
if (((adapterPosition < 14) && (item.dayOfMonth > 14)) || ((adapterPosition > 28) && (item.dayOfMonth < 14))) {
                    tvDate.setTextColor(R.color.colourGrey)
                    ivIndicatorEvent.imageAlpha = 25
                    ivIndicatorActivity.imageAlpha = 25
                }
```

Above code changing alpha, means indicating this dates are not from the current month. you need to improve this conditions.

You need to check `is from same month`

```
fun isSameMonth(dayTime : Long, monthTime : Long) : Boolean
{
   //Create 2 instances of Calendar
    var cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    var cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    //set the given date in one of the instance and current date in the other
    cal1.setTimeInMillis(dayTime );
    cal2.setTimeInMillis(monthTime);
    
    //now compare the dates using methods on Calendar
    if(cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        if(cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
           return true
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you have date object or milliseconds in your item model,

```
if(isSameMonth(item.dayTime, currentSelectedMonthTime))
{
         tvDate.setTextColor(R.color.colourGrey)
         ivIndicatorEvent.imageAlpha = 25
         ivIndicatorActivity.imageAlpha = 25
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ashvin, thanks for you comments. 

Appologies, there are dot indicators on each tile which are used to display an appointment (event or activity). In the images provided there are no records so the dots dont appear at all. If they did I would like them to be only partially visible if they are on dates for the next or previous month. 

I'll add some more code for clarity, however I'm not calling notifyDatasetChanged() as the list is submitted via an observer. The list is provided by a flow so all tiles are updated together. See change in tile numbers between top and bottom image.